# Something changes selinux context on ~jenkins/.ssh/ files

Tags: selinux

From time to time, something changes selinux context on ~jenkins/.ssh file:

```
# restorecon -Fnv ~jenkins/.ssh/authorized_keys
restorecon reset /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/authorized_keys context system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0->system_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 
# restorecon -Fnv ~jenkins/.ssh
restorecon reset /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh context system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0->system_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0
```

1. How to track what can change this context?
2. How to detect this change?

Ad2. I can trigger a hook, via monit program or something similar, which invokes the script with restorecon. However, I can't trace this change in the logs, I don't know how.

Finally, the Jenkins agent cannot run, because it cannot use the ssh key.

`aureport -a` reports nothing, `sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log` also noting, and `audit2allow -aw` is silent as well.

The new, broken context, matches the docker but I'm not sure. The SELinux is in enforcing mode, and with the targeted type.

**Edit:**

Added command:
`auditctl -w /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/authorized_keys -p wa -k jenkins-authorized_keys` and waiting for `ausearch -k jenkins-authorized_keys`